# Override Process Delegate in Update Contract Price

Tags: acumatica

I have been trying to override the Process Delegate for the page "Update Contract Price".

```
public ContractPriceUpdate()
        {
            Items.SetSelected<ContractDetail.selected>();
            Items.SetProcessDelegate<ContractMaint>(UpdatePrices);
            Items.SetProcessCaption(Messages.Update);
            Items.SetProcessAllCaption(Messages.UpdateAll);

            PXUIFieldAttribute.SetDisplayName<Contract.contractCD>(Caches[typeof(Contract)], Common.Messages.Identifier);
        }

protected static void UpdatePrices(ContractMaint graph, ContractDetail item)
    {
        Contract contract = PXSelect<Contract, Where<Contract.contractID, Equal<Required<Contract.contractID>>>>.Select(graph, item.ContractID);

        using (PXTransactionScope ts = new PXTransactionScope())
        {
            if (contract.IsTemplate != true)
            {
                ContractMaintExt contractMaintExt = CreateInstance<ContractMaintExt>();
                contractMaintExt.Contracts.Current = contract;
                if (contract.IsActive == true && 
                    contract.IsPendingUpdate != true &&
                    contract.Status != Contract.status.PendingActivation)
                {
                    CTBillEngine engine = CreateInstance<CTBillEngine>();
                    engine.Upgrade(contract.ContractID);
                    engine.Clear();
                    contractMaintExt.Contracts.Current = PXSelect<Contract, Where<Contract.contractID, Equal<Required<Contract.contractID>>>>.Select(engine, item.ContractID);
                    item = PXSelect<ContractDetail,
                        Where<ContractDetail.contractID, Equal<Required<ContractDetail.contractID>>,
                            And<ContractDetail.lineNbr, Equal<Required<ContractDetail.lineNbr>>>>>.Select(engine, item.ContractID, item.LineNbr);
                }
                contractMaintExt.ContractDetails.Cache.SetDefaultExt<ContractDetail.basePriceOption>(item);
                contractMaintExt.ContractDetails.Cache.SetDefaultExt<ContractDetail.basePrice>(item);
                contractMaintExt.ContractDetails.Cache.SetDefaultExt<ContractDetail.renewalPriceOption>(item);
                contractMaintExt.ContractDetails.Cache.SetDefaultExt<ContractDetail.renewalPrice>(item);
                contractMaintExt.ContractDetails.Cache.SetDefaultExt<ContractDetail.fixedRecurringPriceOption>(item);
                contractMaintExt.ContractDetails.Cache.SetDefaultExt<ContractDetail.fixedRecurringPrice>(item);
                contractMaintExt.ContractDetails.Cache.SetDefaultExt<ContractDetail.usagePriceOption>(item);
                contractMaintExt.ContractDetails.Cache.SetDefaultExt<ContractDetail.usagePrice>(item);
                contractMaintExt.ContractDetails.Update(item);

                contractMaintExt.Actions.PressSave();
            }
            else
            {
                TemplateMaint templateMaint = CreateInstance<TemplateMaint>();
                templateMaint.Templates.Current = PXSelect<ContractTemplate, Where<ContractTemplate.contractID, Equal<Required<ContractTemplate.contractID>>>>.Select(graph, item.ContractID);
                templateMaint.ContractDetails.Cache.SetDefaultExt<ContractDetail.basePriceOption>(item);
                templateMaint.ContractDetails.Cache.SetDefaultExt<ContractDetail.basePrice>(item);
                templateMaint.ContractDetails.Cache.SetDefaultExt<ContractDetail.renewalPriceOption>(item);
                templateMaint.ContractDetails.Cache.SetDefaultExt<ContractDetail.renewalPrice>(item);
                templateMaint.ContractDetails.Cache.SetDefaultExt<ContractDetail.fixedRecurringPriceOption>(item);
                templateMaint.ContractDetails.Cache.SetDefaultExt<ContractDetail.fixedRecurringPrice>(item);
                templateMaint.ContractDetails.Cache.SetDefaultExt<ContractDetail.usagePriceOption>(item);
                templateMaint.ContractDetails.Cache.SetDefaultExt<ContractDetail.usagePrice>(item);
                templateMaint.ContractDetails.Update(item);
                templateMaint.Actions.PressSave();
            }
            ts.Complete();
        }
    }
```

Here I need to customize this condition:

```
if (contract.IsActive == true && 
                    contract.IsPendingUpdate != true &&
                    contract.Status != Contract.status.PendingActivation)
```

I tried to override the constructor to with my own custom static method where I would rewrite all the code but change the condition like this, but it is not working:

```
public override void Initialize()
        {
            var processDelegate = (PXProcessingBase<ContractDetail>.ProcessListDelegate)Base.Items.GetProcessDelegate();
            Base.Items.SetProcessDelegate<ContractMaint>(UpdatePricesProc);
        }
        #region Event Handlers

        public static void UpdatePricesProc(ContractMaint graph, ContractDetail item)
        {
            Contract contract = PXSelect<Contract, Where<Contract.contractID, Equal<Required<Contract.contractID>>>>.Select(graph, item.ContractID);
        }
```

Need help to figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: Your code looks fine, what exactly is not working? Did you try to check if method UpdatePricesProc is called?

Comment: Yeah, I put a debugger on it. But, when I click on Update All, the custom code is not being triggered.

Comment: This one isn't working too.
`public override void Initialize()
        {
            Base.Items.SetProcessDelegate<ContractMaint>(delegate(ContractMaint contractMaint, ContractDetail contractDetail)
            {
                UpdatePricesProc(contractMaint, contractDetail);
            });
        }

        protected static void UpdatePricesProc(ContractMaint graph, ContractDetail item)
        {
            Contract contract = PXSelect<Contract, Where<Contract.contractID, Equal<Required<Contract.contractID>>>>.Select(graph, item.ContractID);
        }`

Comment: Yeah. It turns out my code was fine. The problem was, I have had no Contracts related to that Contract Item and wasn't executing the code. Once, I managed to get pull contracts related to the items, it executed. Thanks for your help.